# Python not reading valid JSON

Tags: python, html, json, string, encoding

I am scraping some HTML source from a web page to extract data stored in a json format

This is the Code:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY'
result = requests.get(url)

c = result.content
html = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
scripts = html.find_all('script')

sl =[]
for s in scripts:

     sl.append(s)

s = (sl[-3])
s = s.contents
s = str(s)
s = s[119:-16]

json_data = json.loads(s)
```

Running the above throws this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 7506 (char7505)
```

When I take the content of variable s and pass it to a json formatter it's recognized as proper json.

I used the following web site to check the json:
http://jsonprettyprint.com/json-pretty-printer.php

Why is this error coming up when using json.loads() in Python? I am assuming it has something to do with the string not being encoded properly or the presence of escape characters?

How do I solve this?

Comment: could u print your JSON before json.loads. You must be missing some kind of delimiter in there

Comment: The json object is too big for me to post here as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON contains certain unexpected tokens like `true`. Use `json.dumps` first to resolve it.

```
print (json.dumps(s,indent =2))
s = json.dumps(s)
json_data = json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 7484 (char 7483)
```

Using the failure message, you can print a slice of the string to see where it is failing.

```
print(s[7400:7500])
mailboxes.isPrimary=\\"true\\" AND ymreq
```

As skaul05 stated, it is failing because of the `true` token in the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY'
result = requests.get(url)

c = result.content
html = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
scripts = html.find_all('script')

sl =[]
for s in scripts:

     sl.append(s)

s = (sl[-3])
s = s.contents

a = s[0][111:-12]

jjjj = json.loads(a)
```

there's somethingrong when you deal with the list,you just use `str()`

Comment: why? it's just where you wrong? why give me such an evaluation?

Comment: can you solve this problem by the method the second one provide? hehe

Answer (score -1):

If it was a valid JSON formatted text then the parser wouldn't complain. This is how I tested it

```
//first I scraped that page
curl https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY > SPY.json
//then tried to parse it using json
a = open("SPY.json")
b = json.load(a)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

You probably need to first parse it in to valid xml first.